How to run Dapr Placement API?
I am trying to check Dapr Placement table to make sure it is keeping my correct Dapr actors address and port via this reference https://docs.dapr.io/reference/api/placement_api/
Dapr version:
CLI version: 1.14.1
Runtime version: 1.14.4
Dapr Placement was deployed on Docker Desktop by default

I am trying to get Dapr Placement table as per Dapr Placement API document above:
GET
http://localhost:healthzPort/placement/state
I suppose healthzPort for Dapr Placement would be one of the ports: 6050, 58080 or 59090. But only port 59090 is returning data which is totally NOT Placement table. The Request GET http://localhost:59090/placement/state is returning below data:
HELP dapr_placement_actor_heartbeat_timestamp The actor's heartbeat timestamp (in seconds) was last reported to the placement service.
TYPE dapr_placement_actor_heartbeat_timestamp gauge
dapr_placement_actor_heartbeat_timestamp{actor_type="MyActor",app_id="myapp",host_name="192.168.86.20:62433",host_namespace="default",pod_name=""} 1.732690885e+09
dapr_placement_actor_heartbeat_timestamp{actor_type="MyActor",app_id="myapp",host_name="192.168.86.20:62872",host_namespace="default",pod_name=""} 1.732690961e+09
Can anyone get Dapr Placement Table from Dapr Placement API? and what is healthz port for Placement Service?
Thank you
Updated 28/11/2024:
I found out that healthz port inside docker is 8080 based on Dapr Placement log
2024-11-11 09:10:05 time="2024-11-10T22:10:05.252515664Z" level=info msg="Healthz server is listening on [::]:8080" instance=f674d06008fe scope=dapr.placement type=log ver=1.14.4
And I also found out a similar question before:
https://github.com/dapr/cli/issues/800
But a GET to http://localhost:58080/placement/state still returns 404 page not found.
The Dapr Placement API reference is saying:

To enable the placement metadata in self-hosted mode you can either set DAPR_PLACEMENT_METADATA_ENABLED environment variable or metadata-enabled command line args on the Placement service to true

But I don't know how to do it when initialize Dapr in self-hosted mode with docker which is simply by: dapr init
Any help?
